# count no.of images

Tags: iphone

hi Guys I have worked on Application and I am trying to Count the No of images in my resource folder and display no.of images in the Simulator 
Could any body tll me how  to do ?
give me code

Comment: If there are still unclear points in this, then **edit the question**. Don't re-post unless it is a different question.

Comment: Also, for future reference, "Give me code" is not the best way to ask for help on a specific issue.  We're not here to write your application for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, you'll need to use `NSFileManager` to look through the contents of `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]` (the path of your app bundle) to find all the files with the right extension.

A better question: why do you want to do this?

**Edit:** alright, if you insist, you'll have to do something like this:

```
NSEnumerator *iter = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryEnumeratorAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
int count = 0; // number of images
for (NSString *path in iter) { // iterate through all files in the bundle
    if ([[path pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]) { // test if the extension is "png"
        count++; // increment the number of images
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        // do other things with the image
    }
}
```

Comment: hi im new to this Technology that is the reason i m trying in all aspects , could you tell me please wot to do next

Comment: im trying now if any doubts regarding i vll  update u in 10  mins 

Thanks Alot jtbandes