# How to add a directory structure with duplicate filenames to a project?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsbundle

I have a directory that boils down to this:

```
/ 
 - character0 -- attribute0 -- image.png
 - character1 -- attribute0 -- image.png
```

I dropped it in XCode, in order to define two characters. Now I would like to load each image.png

```
CIImage * cheetah = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                     URLForResource:@"image" withExtension:@".png"]];
```

What is cheetah ? How can I get `character0` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343759/count-of-images-in-my-nsbundle-mainbundle-bundlepath

Comment: @Nag_iphone There have been changes in the API. Code doesn't compile any more, but I get the idea.

Comment: ok but ....if know the answer  let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just add two files "image.png" to your project, both will be copied to the top-level directory of the application bundle, so that you end with only one file "image.png" in the app.

If you drag the folders "character0", "character1" onto your project and choose the option "Create folder references for any added folders", then the entire folder hierarchies will be copied to the application bundle, and you can reference the resources separately with e.g.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"image"
                                     withExtension:@"png" 
                                      subdirectory:@"character0/attribute0"];
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the list of every URL recursively in a directory for all png files, without using a `[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:` ? Or anything that can be used directly to load an image in a CIImage or a UIImage .

Comment: @Antoine: Sorry, I don't understand your question. To get all URLs recursively, you have to use `enumeratorAtPath` or `enumeratorAtURL`. - What do you mean by *"anything that can be used directly to load an image in a CIImage"* ?

Comment: I mean an object that is accepted in an init method of UIImage or CIImage.

Comment: `enumeratorAtURL` sounds promising. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Antoine: Did you have a chance to check my answer? Did it work? - Please let me know if you need more information, otherwise it would be nice if you "accept" the answer.