# UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile correct pathForResource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have resources:

```
Test.png
test1.jpg
tesT2.jpg
tEst3.jpg
```

I need to show this image in `UIImageView`. So I wrote:

```
imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[myObject.filename stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[myObject.filename pathExtension]]];
```

`myObject` is entity in my model. I get `filename` from xml, but in xml it have format like:

```
filename="test.png"
filename="test1.jpg"
filename="test3.jpg"
filename="test3.jpg"
```

So my Image is `(null)` because in pathForResource I search `@"test" ofType "png"`, but need `@"Test" ofType"png"`.

How I can get correct resources without renaming them?

Comment: Without renaming them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't rename the source data (which you should do really), then you would need to use the file manager to get a list of all of the files available and then do a case insensitive filter to get the matching name and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all resources from bundle see answers here [Count of images in my NSBundle mainBundle bundlePath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7345572/1403732)  and manually check names of image that need to load

Answer (score 1):

You should get the list of files in your bundle with the appropriate extension with

```
NSArray *files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:[myObject.filename pathExtension] inDirectory:nil];
```

Now you go through the array `files` and try to match your filename. This is done using NSArray's method `- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` (clean way) or by looping through the array (old school way).

Predicates are described in the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).

For the old school method, simply loop like this:

```
for (String *file in files)
{
    if ([file caseInsensitiveCompare:myObject.filename] == NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        // do whatever you need to do with the file

        break; // stop the loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**How I can get correct resources without renaming them?**

`Basically iOS contains HFSX file system which is case sensitive. So without renaming the files it is not possible to get the correct resources.` Refer [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83671/what-filesystem-does-ios-use)

`Also the other alternative is, as @wain said, if you have file store in any directory, then you can just parse from that directory and then do a case insensitive filter to get the matching name and use that for fetching the exact filename from directory and then pass into`pathForResource`of`NSBundle`api.` [Refer this for getting the list of file names from directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683345/cycle-through-a-directory-and-get-paths-of-all-the-files-and-folders/18688333#18688333)